# Google Developper API doesn't work with Android Signed APK

Tags: android, google-play-developer-api, signed-apk

I'm coding an Android native application that contains subscriptions purchases.
I have a problem with the **Purchases.subscriptions: get** service of the Google Play Developer API.


Here's my code :

```
            TokenResponse tokenResponse = new TokenResponse();
            tokenResponse.setAccessToken(ACCESS_TOKEN);
            tokenResponse.setRefreshToken(REFRESH_TOKEN);
            tokenResponse.setExpiresInSeconds(3600L);
            tokenResponse.setScope("https://www.googleapis.com/auth/androidpublisher");
            tokenResponse.setTokenType("Bearer");

            HttpRequestInitializer credential =  new GoogleCredential.Builder().setTransport(HTTP_TRANSPORT)
                    .setJsonFactory(JSON_FACTORY)
                    .setClientSecrets(GOOGLE_CLIENT_ID, GOOGLE_CLIENT_SECRET)
                    .build()
                    .setFromTokenResponse(tokenResponse);

            AndroidPublisher publisher = new AndroidPublisher.Builder(HTTP_TRANSPORT, JSON_FACTORY, credential).
                    setApplicationName("MyApp").
                    build();

            AndroidPublisher.Purchases purchases = publisher.purchases();
            AndroidPublisher.Purchases.Subscriptions.Get get = purchases.subscriptions().get("com.myapp.app.android", mSubscriptionId, mPurchaseToken);

            SubscriptionPurchase subscripcion = get.execute();
```

When i'm in debug mode, this part of the code works perfectly and the **Subscriptions.Get** service respond OK with the detail json that correspond to the parameter *mPurchaseToken*
Example of URL service on the app logs in debug mode :

```
DetailSubs: http : https://www.googleapis.com/androidpublisher/v3/applications/com.myapp.app.android/purchases/subscriptions/sub_1_month/tokens/[mPurchaseToken]
```

But when i test the app with a Generated Signed APK, the **Subscriptions.Get** service doesn't work and i have this stacktrace :

```
 System.err: d.e.c.a.b.d.b: 404 Not Found
 W System.err: Not Found
 I System.out: [CDS]close[45832]
 I System.out: close [socket][/0.0.0.0:45832]
 W System.err:    at d.e.c.a.b.f.d.b.a()
 W System.err:    at d.e.c.a.b.f.d.b.a()
 W System.err:    at d.e.c.a.b.f.b$a.a()
[...]
```

Example of URL service on the app logs in "Signed APK" mode :

```
DetailSubs: http : https://www.googleapis.com/androidpublisher/v3/applications//purchases/subscriptions//tokens/?m=sub_1_month
```

**Can you help me to find the source of this anomaly please ?**

Thanks for your help.

**EDIT :** 
 Moreover, i use this version of the "Google Play Developer API V3" library :

```
compile 'com.google.apis:google-api-services-androidpublisher:v3-rev129-1.25.0'
```

Comment: you have to slashes in the second url, //purchases and //tokens, is that intentional and could be that part of the reason?

Comment: @Erti-Chris Eelmaa thanks for your comment. Yes, i also think this is the reason why there are an "404 Not Found" error. But the URL is generated by the code in my post and the // are not intentional. I don't understand why this works in debug mode and not with a signed APK with the same parameters.